# SonarQube analysis failed in VSTS with Remote Agent

Tags: java, sonarqube, azure-devops

SonarQube analysis failed in VSTS with Remote Agent but working fine in hosted agent. Java path is set correctly in my remote machine where the agent is installed  "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92" ... still facing the same issue

```
> SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value
> of -Xmx1024m Calling the SonarQube Scanner... ERROR: JAVA_HOME exists
> but does not point to a valid Java home folder. No "\bin\java.exe"
> file can be found there. The SonarQube Scanner did not complete
> successfully 08:21:27.994  Creating a summary markdown file...
> Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1 System.Exception: Unexpected exit
> code received from batch file: 1 at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeBatchScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
> at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
> Waiting on the SonarQube server to finish processing in order to
> determine the quality gate status.
> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot determine if the
> analysis has finished. Possible cause: your SonarQube server version
> is lower than 5.3 - for more details see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722407 --->
> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot determine if the
> analysis has finished. Possible cause: your SonarQube server version
> is lower than 5.3 - for more details see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722407
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable
> input) at
> System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace
> rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke) at
> System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace
> rsToUse, Boolean isSync) at
> System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1
> input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings) at
> System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1
> input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings) at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.PowerShellHandler.Execute(ITaskContext
> context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 timeoutInMinutes)
> at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.RunTask(ITaskContext
> context, TaskWrapper task, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
> ****************************************************************************** Finishing task: SonarQubePostTest
> ****************************************************************************** System.Exception: Task SonarQubePostTest failed. This caused the job
> to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details. at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext
> jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension,
> CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
> ****************************************************************************** Finishing Build
> ******************************************************************************
```

Comment: explicit ERROR: JAVA_HOME exists but does not point to a valid Java home folder. No "\bin\java.exe" file can be found there. Check in command windows "java -version" do you add java in path variable but you need also create a JAVA_HOME variable

Comment: ya i have given path too %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java

Comment: in variable path add just %JAVA_HOME%\bin  did you try java -version command ?

Comment: ya with %JAVA_HOME%\bin also i tried still the same error.....on trying this command java -version i get  this java version "1.8.0_92"

Comment: its done...i just restarted the remote machine and its working.